# Multiple joins, average on one table, count on another

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql

I have four tables in a database: City, User, CityRating, CityGreeting. The CityRating table has the UserID and CityID as the PK, and those are FKs to the USer and City table.  The CityGreeting table has no PK, but has the UserID and CityID as FKs (the idea is that a user can greet a city as many times as desired, but only rate a city once).

I am trying to write a query that will return the average rating of the city overall, as well as the times a specific user greeted the city:

```
select City.CityID, City.CityName, City.CityStateOrProvince, 
ROUND(AVG(Cast(RateCity.Rating as float)), 2) as AverageRating,
(select COUNT(HelloCity.CityID) from HelloCity where HelloCity.UserID like '<guid>') as TimesVisited
from City
right join RateCity
on City.CityID = RateCity.CityID
right join HelloCity
on City.CityID = HelloCity.CityID
group by City.CityID, City.CityName,
City.CityStateOrProvince, City.CityCountry, City.CityImageUri
```

Even if I can get this to work as expected (which it currently is not) I feel like it is really messy. In terms of best practices, would it be better to write two queries? This operation would be performed in an api, not sure if the performance would be better on writing two seperate queries instead, or one complex one like this.  Any insight on this or how to get the query to work as expected?

***EDIT: Added picture to clarify: Average Rating is the average of all users who rated, and TimesVisited is the amount of times one specific user has visited the city.

[image: Added picture to clarify: Average Rating is the average of all users who rated, and TimesVisited is the amount of times one specific user has visited the city.]

Comment: what are you using UserId like '' for? Shouldn't you be saying where UserID =  and also the City.CityId = HelloCity.CityId ?

Comment: Can you add sample data and expected result

Comment: I have added a picture of the results to clarify - the only thing incorrect in the picture is the TimesVisited column - it is supposed to show the number of times a specific user has visited each city

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need to aggregate the tables, apart from `city` separately for this to work correctly:

```
select c.*, rc.AverageRating, coalesce(hc.TimesVisited, 0) as TimesVisited
from City c join
     (select CityId, ROUND(AVG(Cast(RateCity.Rating as float)), 2) as AverageRating
      from RateCity rc
      group by CityId
     ) rc
     on c.CityID = rc.CityID left join
     (select CityId, count(*) as TimesVisited
      from HelloCity hc
      where hc.UserID like '<guid>'
      group by CityId
     ) hc
     on c.CityId = hc.CityId;
```

Notes:

- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- I doubt you really mean `right join`.  That would imply that there are `CityId`s in the other two tables that are not in `City`.
- By doing the aggregation for each other table, you don't need an aggregation in the outer query.
- I do think you want a `left join` for the `HelloCity` table, because not all cities might have visitors.
- You might want a `left join` for the `RateCity` table as well, if not all cities have ratings.

Comment: That is really impressive. Thank you for that. Great explanation as well

Comment: I was hoping to ask about the syntax of the query - I see that c is an alias for City - can you explain what the part in parenthesis is doing?  Is it just getting the "columns" of the alias as defined by the select in the parenthesis?

Comment: @KateMak . . . The parts in parentheses are subqueries.

Answer (score 2):

why don't you use a CTE and then do the individual parts in each CTE, it helps to break it down instead of trying to mash together bunch of joins: for example:

```
DECLARE @userId VARCHAR(10) = 'userid1' ;

WITH 

CITY_RATING_CTE (cityId, AverageRating) AS
  ( SELECT cityId,
           AVG(Rating) AS rating
   FROM RateCity
   GROUP BY cityId),

TIMES_VISITED_CTE AS
  ( SELECT cityId,
           count(*) AS TimesVisited
   FROM HelloCity
   WHERE UserId = @userId
   GROUP BY cityId)
SELECT c.CityId,
       c.CityName,
       c.CityStateOrProvince,
       c.CityImageUri,
       cr.AverageRating,
       tv.TimesVisited
FROM City c
JOIN CITY_RATING_CTE cr ON cr.cityId = c.CityId
JOIN TIMES_VISITED_CTE tv ON cr.cityId = cr.cityId;
```

Comment: added userid in the query